# Python Selenium xpath white spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I would like to get usernames from one page, but for some reason I just can't get it working..

After browsing internet and other Stackoverflow posts; I think the problem is that there are white spaces in `@class`, and it just doesn't work. Then I found solution to do it the other way, but the problem is that after first class, I would like to go to second class as well, and this is the only way I know I can do it with `find_elements_by_xpath`.

[Picture to inspect element of what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChhXU.png)

In this picture, 'text' is one of the usernames it should scrap.

My code:

```
usernames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='kik-widget card card-just-text card-with-shadow']//h3[@class='kik-widget-text-muted']")
usernames2 = [x.text for x in usernames]
print(usernames2)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The h3 element from your input is found, what else do you want exactly to match with your XPath?

Comment: I want that it prints the username, which is "text" in this case.

Comment: Are there more than one h3 tags in your code. You can easily use find_element_by_tagname() method and check the getText() method to get the text from there.

Comment: Yes there are more h3 tags in the code, find_element_by_tagname() wouldn't be the option I could go here, because there is one more xpath like in orginal post, everything is same, it just has promoted in class as well, that's why I want to exclude that and get directly via that xpath,

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `contains` in your case to avoid spaces.
For example:

`//h3[contains(@class, 'kik-widget-text-muted')`

Contains will skip spaces.

Hope this will help you.